# How to check the selected video is compressed video or not in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, video-compression

**I want to upload video without compressing, if the video is alrady compressed.**

I want to upload a video from local storage to server

dependancy :
video_compress: ^3.1.0

I used to compress video with video_compress: ^3.1.0 package.
Its working perfectly.
But, when i upload a compressed video again it takes more time to compress.
**So i want to upload without compressing, if the video is alrady compressed.**

here is my code to compress a video

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
    result.files.single.path,
    quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality,
    deleteOrigin: false, // It's false by default
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print video size

```
print(mediaInfo!.filesize!);
```